# Android: Canvas scaling in different coordinate system

Tags: java, android, canvas, coordinates, scale

I'm kinda desperate already =)...

I'am drawing points and lines onto a canvas in Android. The points I'm displaying should be displayed in a mathematical system. So I did canvas.getHeight() - point.y to display the points in the right way.

But if I would like to zoom into the drawn object the y coordinate gets scaled out of my view.
That's because x = 10 and y = 700. If I scale it with a scale factor of 10, the y make the object disappear.
I hope you get what I'm talking about...

How do I display my coordinates in the right (mathematical) way without moving the y coordinate far away??

Here is what I do:

```
        canvas.drawPoint(startPoints[i][0], height-startPoints[i][1], pointColor);
        canvas.drawPoint(endPoints[i][0], height-endPoints[i][1], pointColor);
```

Then my point (x=10, y=10) is going to be displayed as x=10 , y = 714.

Here's my full routine

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    final float[][] startPoints;

    final float[][] endPoints;

    int count = 0;
    height = canvas.getHeight();

    canvas.save();
    canvas.scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
    canvas.translate(translateX / scaleFactor, translateY / scaleFactor);

    Paint lineColor = new Paint();
    lineColor.setColor(Color.BLACK);

    Paint pointColor = new Paint();
    pointColor.setColor(Color.RED);
    pointColor.setStrokeWidth(5f);

    startPoints = data.getStartPoints();
    endPoints = data.getEndPoints();
    count = data.getSize();

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        canvas.drawLine(startPoints[i][0], height-startPoints[i][1],
                endPoints[i][0], height-endPoints[i][1], lineColor);
        canvas.drawPoint(startPoints[i][0], height-startPoints[i][1], pointColor);
        canvas.drawPoint(endPoints[i][0], height-endPoints[i][1], pointColor);
    }

    canvas.restore();
}

private class ScaleListener extends
        ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        scaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();
        scaleFactor = Math.max(MIN_ZOOM, Math.min(scaleFactor, MAX_ZOOM));
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend familiarizing yourself with the drawing coordinate system of canvas as it's very common in computer graphics and will make your life much easier than trying to change the coordinate system. I'm also not sure how you're scaling that would make the point disappear. Could you post some code?

Comment: I'm scaling with the ScaleGestureDetector. I post some code below

Answer (score 0):

scaling factor x = screen width in pixels / target width in pixels

scaling factor y = screen height in pixels / target height in pixels

or

scaled x point = x on resized canvas * (resized width / original width)

scaled y point = y on resized canvas * (resized height / original height)

Comment: the target width and height would be the distance between my fingers which I'm zooming with?

Comment: target width is the original width before resizing and screen width is the current resized width

Comment: well this is not the problem... Imaging a point with x=1 and y=500. You have a screen which displays 400x700 pixels. If you scale the point by a scaling factor of 2, you will have x=2 and y=1000. So the points gets pushed out of the canvas and you have to pan down to it. thats what I would like to avoid

Comment: I just need to find out how to flip my y values so I dont get a mirrored object

Comment: Maybe would better keep your canvas size static and calculate the rect destiny and origin of the bitmap you draw inside the canvas. Therefore you could use scaling factor calc without change the canvas dimensions. I hope it helps